# Inline referencing of a code chunk in document

Tags: r, r-markdown

Suppose there is a code chunk as follows:

````
```{r mean diff} 
(5-mean(dnorm(40,5,2))/5 
```
````

I would like to be able to reference this code chunk with its label in inline form in a markdown document, so that the reference is replaced by the output of this chunk. Is there a way to do it?

```
" the difference is `r mean diff` %."    ##something like this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is "yes, but it's tricky".  By default `knitr` doesn't save the last value computed in a code chunk.  In regular code, the last value calculated is saved in `.Last.value`, but `knitr` doesn't simulate this.

However, a simple modification lets you do something very similar:

````
```{r} 
meandiff <- 5-mean(dnorm(40,5,2))/5
meandiff   # if you want the chunk to print its value 
```
````

and then in the text, use

```
" the difference is `r meandiff` %."
```

If you really want to save the last value, it's possible by setting a "render hook".  For example, the code below saves the last value, then calls the old hook:

````
```{r}
.Last.value <- NULL
old_hook <- knitr::opts_chunk$get("render")

knitr::opts_chunk$set(render = function(x, options, ...) {
  .Last.value <<- x
  if (!is.null(old_hook))
    old_hook(x, options, ...)
  else
   knitr::knit_print(x, options, ...)
})
```

```{r mean diff} 
5-mean(dnorm(40,5,2))/5 
```

The value was `r .Last.value`.
````

Comment: I thought of this too as this did solve this problem, so thank you for your answer. But I also wanted to know if what I asked was possible, you believe it's not. Could you tell me why? Is there no such option available in markdown code chunks yet? If there a package that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Turns out I was wrong, it is possible, but you need the tricky code I added to my answer.

Comment: So would I have to add this code before/after every code chunk that I use or will defining it in a global environment, maybe as a "setup" chunk, work? Since it assigns the value globally, I think it should work if I set this code in the beginning of the document, right?

Comment: And also, basically it is not possible to refer a code chunk by its label inline. It's only possible to access variables, right?

Comment: The render hook I gave you can't do that, but you could write another function that did, since the labels are available to the render hook as `options$label`.